# How do i give ssh keys for multiple hosts from terminal command line in fabric

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I want to test various package installation on multiple hosts. Different hosts have different password/ssh-key.

I dont want to hard code host name and their ssh-key in my fab file. How can i pass multiple host and their ssh-key through terminal command line.

Code in my fab file looks like -

```
    from fabric.api import settings, run, env

    def test_installation(cmd):
    run("dpkg -s %s" %cmd)
```

And i am calling it like -

```
    fab test_installation:tomcat7 --hosts "user1@host1:port","vuser2@host2:port" -i "ssh-file-path for host1","ssh-file-path for host2"
```

Please suggest me the proper way. any help is most welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide ssh keys of **hosts**, but only **your ssh key**, that is used to register you in authorized_keys on host. And you provide only path to it (usually it is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`).

Moreover,  you can configure fabric to use your ssh config, so you don't need to hardcode any path at all. It can use the same keys, as it would use if you typed `ssh my_host` in shell.

How to do that you can find in fabric tutorial:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#leveraging-native-ssh-config-files

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#full-list-of-env-vars

You can also set your ~/.ssh/config to use different key for different host.
If you are not familiar with ssh and configuring it, please see:

http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Comment: Thanks for answer.The only prob is i have to call this from ruby script and i don't have any way to register my host machine with different virtual machines. I only have various private-keys of virtual machines. Is there any way where i can pass virtual machines private keys and able to connect to them ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine and remember: not private, but __public keys__

Comment: Yes it was a mistake... public key.

Comment: ssh-copy-id -i "user@host -p2222" is promting me for password for user@host, which i dont have. I have only public key of host.. :(

Comment: You really should read how ssh key based authentication works. You copy __your public key__ to host. You can do this manually, copying content of your `id_rsa.pub` to `/home/$USER_ON_HOST/.ssh/authorized_keys` (create this file if it does not exist). And later I would disable ssh password authentication whatsoever. And read a lot about ssh authentication and asymetric cryptography...